# How to query multiple boards in Monday using its API?

Tags: monday.com

Can anyone know how to query multiple boards ids with Monday API?

For a single board following code is correct:

```
query = '{ boards (ids: 99999999) { name id description items { name column_values{title id type text } } } }'
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
... boards (ids: 99999999, 8888888, 77777777) ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in the answer:

boards (ids: [99999999, 8888888, 77777777])

Comment: Please do not provide link only answers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer